# Existence of an ideal with no nilpotents but with the same radical

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be any commutative ring with a unit. Let $I$ be an ideal in $A$. Is there an ideal $I'$ such that $\sqrt{I}=\sqrt{I'}$ and $I' \cap \operatorname{nil}(A)=0$?

Motivation:  I am trying to show that if $Spec A$ is separated, then $A=B\times C$ for some nonzero rings $B$ and $C$.  If $Spec A$ is separated by $V(I_1)$ and $V(I_2)$, then $I_1 \cap I_2\subset nil A$ and $I_1 + I_2=A$.  I would like to be able to say that $I_1 \times I_2\cong A$ and I would be closer to doing this if I could at least get a direct sum decomposition.  I would be able to get this if I were able to replace $I_1$ and $I_2$ with the ideals that I am looking for above.

Comment: Let $I' = \sqrt{I}$.  Then your condition holds.  So a special case of your question is: in a reduced ring $A$, is every ideal equal to its radical?   What do you think?

Comment: @tracing Why do you say the condition holds when $I' = \sqrt{I}$? Isn't $\operatorname{nil}(A) = \sqrt{0} \subseteq \sqrt{I}$?

Comment: @Jay: Sorry, I misread the question.  Looking at it again, I see that if nil$(A) =0$, then we can just take $I = I'$.  And that the answer is *yes* if $A$ is Noetherian (but I'm unsure about the general case right now).  Sorry about that.

Comment: OP: if you take $I = \operatorname{nil}(A) \ne 0$ then no such $I'$ exists

Comment: One way to do your problem is to reduce to the case where $A$ is reduced because $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec}(A/\operatorname{nil}(A))$. Then if $I_1 + I_2 = A$ and $I_1 \cap I_2 = 0$ then $A = A/I_1 \cap I_2 = A/I_1 \times A/I_2$ by Chinese Remainder Theorem

Comment: What do you mean "separated"? Not connected?

Comment: @Jay What about $I'=0$ for $I=\mathrm{nil}(A)$?

Comment: @user26857: You're definitely right $I' = 0$ works for the case I gave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not always possible.  For instance, take $A=k[x,y]/(y^2)$ for a field $k$ and let $I=(x)$.  Note that for any nonzero $a\in A$, either $a$ or $ay$ is a nonzero nilpotent (if $a$ is divisible by $y$, then $a$ is nilpotent; if not, then $ay\neq 0$ is nilpotent).  So any nonzero ideal must contain nonzero nilpotents.  Since $\sqrt{I}\neq\sqrt{0}$, any $I'$ such that $\sqrt{I'}=\sqrt{I}$ thus contains nonzero nilpotents.